# react-select Render custom component as SingleValue

Tags: react-select

I need to display an icon before the selected value using `react-select` and typescript.

This is what I tried so far:

```
SingleValue: React.SFC<SingleValueProps<OptionType>> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <components.SingleValue {...props}>
      <i className={`fal fa-${this.props.icon} has-text-grey-light`} /> {children}
    </components.SingleValue>
  )
```

The main issue is with type definitions that expects that children passed to `components.SingleValue` must be a string.

Comment: Could you try to recreate your case in http://codesandbox.io, I'm not sure to see your exact issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don´t have to use the standard components. You can easlily create a custom one but still keep the styles it needs.

The only requirement you need is `emotion` to get the styles the `SingleValue` component uses.

```
/**
 * This Example uses the `FontAwesome` React library.
**/

const options = [
  { label: "Value A", value: "a", icon: faCoffee },
  { label: "Value B", value: "b", icon: faCar },
  { label: "Value C", value: "c", icon: faMobile },
  { label: "Value D", value: "d", icon: faCircle },
  { label: "Value E", value: "e", icon: faSquare }
];

const SingleValue = ({
  cx,
  getStyles,
  selectProps,
  data,
  isDisabled,
  className,
  ...props
}) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div
      className={cx(
        emotionCss(getStyles("singleValue", props)),
        {
          "single-value": true,
          "single-value--is-disabled": isDisabled
        },
        className
      )}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={data.icon} style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />
      <div>{selectProps.getOptionLabel(data)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default class MySelect extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        options={options}
        components={{ SingleValue }}
        styles={{
          singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            display: "flex", // To keep icon and label aligned
            alignItems: "center"
          })
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oojnrvq4n6)